# Adding JMenuBar and JPanel to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

I am having some trouble with adding a JMenuBar and a JPanel to a JFrame, here is my Main Method:

```
public static Timer timer = new Timer(100, ActionListener.repaint);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Insets in;
    frame.setSize(600, 500);
    frame.pack();
    in = frame.getInsets();
    frame.setSize(600 + (in.left + in.right) - 10, 500 + (in.top + in.bottom) - 10);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener());
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);


    menuBar.add(file);
    file.add(add);
    file.add(sub);

    frame.add(gui);
    timer.start();

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The field 'gui' is my JPanel class:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


}
```

Here is my repaint Timer:

```
public static java.awt.event.ActionListener repaint = new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        GUI.gui.repaint();
    }
};
```

here is the output:

[image: You can see it duplicates my JMenuBar]

See how it duplicated the JMenuBar? It does that for anything painted onto that JPanel.
Any solutions?

Comment: Providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would get you help sooner.

Answer (score 1):

> Any solutions?

Yes. Dont call `Thread.sleep` in the `paintComponent` method. In fact dont call `Thread.sleep` anywhere in a Swing application. For periodic delays use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Is that really the problem? Ok Ill give it a shot.

Comment: Yes it is and dont place delaying logic inside the `paintComponent` method. This only blocks the `EDT` preventing UI repaints :)

Comment: Not the problem, I replaced my Thread.sleep with a Swing timer, same problem.

Comment: How about you hit that reload button in your browser, so you can see that I have updated my code.

Comment: What exactly are you using `paintComponent` for? You dont even have `super.paintComponent(g)`. I would remove the method completely. That means the timer isnt needed either...

Comment: I think you just solved my problem. I didn't have super.paintComponent(g), I don't know if thats it, but ill try.